# Formatting a two variable plot animation

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I've seen other posts related to this error, but I'm really struggling to find the root cause of the error.

Basically, I'm trying to animate two lines A and B from values that are read through an Excel file. The plot is fine, but the error message appears when I try to animate it.

[image: A and B plot]

Here is the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(here)
library(scales)
library(reshape)
library(stringr)
library(gganimate)
library(gifski)


real_format <- function(largest_with_cents = 100000) {
  function(x) {
    x <- round_any(x, 0.01)
    if (max(x, na.rm = TRUE) < largest_with_cents &
        !all(x == floor(x), na.rm = TRUE)) {
      nsmall <- 2L
    } else {
      x <- round_any(x, 1)
      nsmall <- 0L
    }
    str_c("R$", format(x, nsmall = nsmall, trim = TRUE, big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ",", scientific = FALSE, digits=1L))
  }
}

AB2000 <- read_excel(here("AxB_2000.xlsx"))

gg_base <- ggplot(data = AB2000) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = as.Date(Date), y = A, colour = "A", group = 1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = as.Date(Date), y = B, colour = "B", group = 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("A" = "blue", "B" = "red"))

gg_base + labs(x = "Year",y = "") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                     breaks=seq(0,14000,1000), 
                     labels=real_format()) +
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
                    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
                    legend.position="none")

gg_base.animation = gg_base + transition_reveal(Date)

animate(gg_base.animation, duration = 2, fps = 30, width = 800, height = 600)
anim_save("test.gif")
```

The excel table is the following:

[image: Data set]

I actually get an animation but it removes all the formatting. How can I keep the formatting from the plot?

[image: .gif animation]

I receive four message errors saying:
`geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation. ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

They don't appear if I don't animate (removing the three last lines of code).

Comment: Do you get an error or a warning? It doesn't really seem like a problem. The message probably comes from the fact that in the beginning, you can't draw a line until you have two points to connect. Remember when you add `+` stuff to a ggplot object, a new object is returned, the object itself is not updated. Since you use `gg_base.animation = gg_base + ...`, the stuff you added like `labs()` and `theme_bw()` didn't get saved to `gg_base`. Make sure to save that new object before trying to animate it.

Comment: Thank you, I removed gg_base.animation and included transition_reveal to gg_base. Now it works fine

Comment: Greetings! Rather than a table of your excel data, usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg